# jQuery - appendTo previous / preceding element

Tags: jquery, appendto

I couldn't find this on here already, and am hoping somebody can help.

I need the link (.more) to be appended to the paragraph that precedes it - I'm sure this is simple enough, but can't quite get it right:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum</p>

<a href="#" class="more">Read more</a>

<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
```

There may be more paragraphs in the final HTML, the reason I need to do this is CMS-related. But based on the above, my aim would be:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum <a href="#" class="more">Read more</a></p>

<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
```

I've tried:

```
$(".more").appendTo("p");
```

But obviously this will append it to all paragraphs... perhaps this is a job for prevAll, but I can't quite put my finger on it.

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<a href="#" class="more">Read more1</a>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<a href="#" class="more">Read more2</a>
```

**JS**

```
$('p').each(function(e){
    if($(this).next('a').hasClass('more'))
       $(this).html($(this).html()+" ").append($(this).next('a')); 
});​
```

[**Example1**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/Me5Dm/7/) and [**Example2 with multiple a tags.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/Me5Dm/6/)

Answer (score 3):

try to use

```
var more = $(".more");
more.prev().append(" ").append(more);
```

Comment: of course `$(".more")` catches all elements with class "more", but it fits to the given example

Comment: I think so just wanted to make you notice.